# how to use KKT conditions for an exponential function

Tags: optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

our teacher gave us a problem in the exam that I failed to answer it even after passing it, and I ask for an explanation from people here please...

this is the problem :

let **K** be a subset of $\Bbb R^2$ such that : $$K=\{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2, \mathrm{e}^{-x} \le y, \quad y \le 2-x,\quad y \le x\}$$ 
and $$ f : \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R $$
the function given by $$ f(x,y) = y\cdot\mathrm{e}^{-x} $$

1/ Show the existence of a solution **(x*,y*)** for the problem $$\mathbf{min} \underset{(x,y) \in K} \quad f(x,y) $$

I know there are many ways for doing that, like showing that **f(x,y)** is continuous and coercive and showing that **K** is closed, or showing that **K** is bounded and closed, means **compact** (I don't know if it is an enough condition for the existence), or showing that **f(x,y)** is strictly convex on the convex set **K**, please tell me which way it is the most efficient.

2/ justify and write the optimality conditions of **KKT** and solve the problem

and here the calamity, I find up to 9 cases that I couldn't at anyone find **x** or **y** --"

Comment: The Lagrangian is $$\mathcal{L}(x,y,\lambda,\mu,\nu)=ye^{-x}+\lambda(e^{-x}-y)+\mu(x+y-2)+\nu(y-x).$$
The KKT conditions are
$$\begin{align*}
-xye^{-x}-\lambda e^{-x}+\mu-\nu=0\\
e^{-x}-\lambda+\mu+\nu=0\\
e^{-x}\leq y\\
x+y\leq 2\\
y\leq x\\
\lambda,\mu,\nu\geq 0\\
\lambda(e^{-x}-y)=0\\
\mu(x+y-2)=0
\\\nu(y-x)=0
\end{align*}$$
Now you just need to check each of the 8 combinations out of the complimentary slackness constraints (the last three).

Comment: thank you so much, I really reached this step, but finding x and y, I always find a  contradiction, I mean like **landa** is negative for example...

Comment: If you set $\nu=\mu=0$, and $e^{-x}=y$, then $(-1,e)$ is a solution with $\lambda=e\geq 0$. So although many of the cases are impossible, there is at least which is possible.

Comment: thank you again, yea I tried them all, like the case that u just said, but it is impossible tho, because **-1** is not in **K** and even **e** isn't in **K**...

Comment: Okay, you are right, my mistake. But still, there is $\nu=0$, $y=e^{-x}$ and $x+y=2$ which gives $x=2+W(-e^{-2})$ and $y=\exp\left(-2-W(-e^{-2})\right)$, and $$\lambda=\frac{1+x(2-x)}{y^{-1}-1}\geq 0$$
$$\mu=\lambda-y\geq 0.$$ You can verify the inequalities by using the fact that $W$ is monotone and $W(-e^{-1})=-1$.

Still, it seems strange that you'd be given this in an exam, I might have made a mistake.

Comment: mmm,I thank you so much :"')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $(x,y) \in K$ then $0<e^{-x} \leq y \leq 2-x$ which gives $x \leq 2$. Also $0<y \leq x\leq 2$. Hence $K$ is bounded. It is also closed, so is $K$ is compact. Since $f$ is continuous it attains its minimum at some point. To minimize $f$ we can minimize over $y$ first and then minimize over $x$. Hence we have to minimize $e^{-2x}$ subject to the conditions $e^{-x} \leq \min \{x,2-x\}$. It is easy to see that there is a unique $t$ such that $e^{t}(2-t)=1$ and $f$ is minimized when $x=t, y=e^{-t}$.

Comment: oooh, thank you so much, I really needed for this, what about the second question please?

Comment: @HansamuKaTuripuMyLuda I have attempted to solve part 2) without Lagrange Mulitpliers, etc. I hope I didn't make any mistake.

Comment: mmm,I thank you so much :"')